# How to rewrite Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_CreateController correct?

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml

I need to override `Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_CreateController` which placed in `app/code/core`. Its **saveAction()** method, actually.

My `config.xml` looks like this: [image: rewriting Mage_Adminhtml in local mmodule]

And `app/code/local/Magestore/Onestepcheckout/controllers/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/CreateController.php` like this:

[image]

`Magestore/Onestepcheckout` module is active now.

There is another class which overrides `Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_CreateController` in local pool, but placing method **saveAction** in there do nothing.

Does Anybody know what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your `config.xml` is wrong I reckon.

You need to replace the following:

```
admin_onestepcheckout
```

With the name of your module so in your case I think it is:

```
Magestore_Onestepcheckout
```

Comment: Well, it gives the same result